# Partition induced from sigma-algebra in Sigma itself?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space. Define $$P(\omega)=\bigcap_{\omega \in F \in \Sigma}F$$
P() induces a equivalence relation: $\forall \omega \in \Omega, \omega \in P(\omega) $. $\forall \omega_1, \omega_2$, if $\exists F \in \Sigma$, such that $\omega_1 \in F, \omega_2 \in \Omega \setminus F$, then $P(\omega_1)\subseteq F$ and $P(\omega_2)\subseteq \Omega \setminus F$, therefore $P(\omega_1) \cap P(\omega_2) = \emptyset$. If no such $F$ exists, then $P(\omega_1) = P(\omega_2)$

Question: is $P(\omega) \in \Sigma$? If not, will it be true if it's a probability space?

If not, is there any other way to get a equivalence class, where the equivalence class inside the algebra? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whether $P(\omega) \in \Sigma$ has nothing to do whether $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ is endowed with a probability. It will be true when $\Omega$ is a topological space with some separability/countability condition, such as first countability, and $\Sigma$ is the Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: @ABlumenthal Because of the equivalence class structure, we can find a smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma'$ containing all the equivalence classes. Then $\Sigma'$ is a larger $\sigma$-algebra derived from the original one. Intuitively that is unlikely to be true, but I can not prove/disprove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your  $P(\omega)$  is called the *atom* of $\Sigma$ determined by $\omega$. In Exercise 5 of Chapter 8, Section 6 of *Measure Theory* by Donald L. Cohn, you prove that atoms are not necessarily measurable.

> Let $X=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{R}$ and let $\cal A$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that makes the coordinate projection of $X$ onto $\{0,1\}$ measurable (of course  $\{0,1\}$ has the $\sigma$-algebra consisting of all of its subsets).
>
> 1. Show that for each $A$ in $\cal A$ there is a countable subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that if $x\in A$, if $y\in X$, and if $x(s)=y(s)$ holds at each $s\in S$, then $y\in A$.
> 2. Show that the atoms of $\cal A$ do not belong to $\cal A$.

Comment: Nice. Reminiscent of the fact that the sigma-algebra generated by the finite subsets of some set $E$ is the whole power set $2^E$ if and only if $E$ is at most countable.